# View pager android code

Tags: java, android

I have a listview if i click a listview 
each list view details is show on another activity 
that on view pager

i.e if i click on first list on a listview thats details should be shown first of the view mpager and left swipe it should display the next listview details on viewpager like that give me sugesstion

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple viewpager from [here](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/09/android-viewpager-simple-tutorial-sliding-screens/)

on listView onClick() you can select corresponding page in viewpager as follows

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
               
        
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);  
               
            }
        });
```

**viewPager** is the object of ViewPager

**position** gives the corresponding row in listview